# Having a problem inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE busi_reg 
    (IN instruc VARCHAR(10), 
     IN tble VARCHAR(20), 
     IN busName VARCHAR(50), IN busCateg VARCHAR(100), 
     IN busType VARCHAR(50), 
     IN phne VARCHAR(20), IN addrs VARCHAR(200), IN cty VARCHAR(50), 
     IN prvnce VARCHAR(50), IN pstCde VARCHAR(10), IN nm VARCHAR(20), 
     IN surname VARCHAR(20), IN eml VARCHAR(50), IN pswd VARCHAR(20), 
     IN srce VARCHAR(50), IN refr VARCHAR(50), IN sess VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN

INSERT INTO b_register SET

       business_name = busName,
       business_category = busCateg,
       business_type = busType,
       phone = phne,
       address = addrs,
       city = cty,
       province = prvnce,
       postal_code = pstCde,
       firstname = nm,
       lastname = surname,
       email = eml,
       password = pswd,
       source = srce,
       ref_no = refr;

END;
```

This is my php script:

```
$busName = $_POST['bus_name'];    
$busCateg = $_POST['bus_cat'];
$busType = $_POST['bus_type'];    
$phne = $_POST['phone'];
$addrs = $_POST['address'];    
$cty = $_POST['city'];    
$prvnce = $_POST['province'];    
$pstCde = $_POST['postCode'];    
$nm = $_POST['name'];    
$surname = $_POST['lname'];    
$eml = $_POST['email'];    
$srce = $_POST['source'];    
$ref = $_POST['ref_no'];

$result2 = $db->query("CALL busi_reg('$instruc', '$tble', '$busName', 
    '$busCateg', '$busType', '$phne', '$addrs', '$cty', '$prvnce', 
    '$pstCde', '$nm', '$surname', '$eml', '$pswd', '$srce', '$refr', '')");

if($result)
{
    echo "Data has been saved";
}
else
{
    printf("Error: %s\n",$db->error);
}
```

Now the error that I get:

```
**Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**
```

Comment: What table type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume because this is tagged MySQLi, that you're using it.

Are you using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT? A quick google search on the error quickly brought me to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

If that is the problem you'll need to free your last result before executing the new one.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It might not be the solution, but it's not misleading.